# Integration of Vue and Vanilla UI-Kit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, uikit

I want to integrate UI-kit completely into my VueJS app without the use of Vui-Kit framework. My css works correctly but the javascript does not work properly (for example data-src attribute is not recognised). I integrated it inside main.js like this.

```
import 'uikit/dist/css/uikit.css'
import 'uikit/dist/js/uikit.js'
```

Can somebody help me with the correct integration?

Comment: did you try  `require('uikit/dist/js/uikit.js')`?

Comment: Nope. Going to check it out thank you for the idea.

Comment: It is done it was an issue with webpack image require() function.